# Recommended word order of names?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

From my perspective there can be (at least) two aproaches how to create a name for a variable, function, class etc.

1. Structured:

   ```
   history_clear()
   history_save_to_file()
   cache_remove_entry()
   cache_find()
   browser_window_url_trim()
   ```
2. Readable for humans:

   ```
   clear_history()
   save_history_to_file()
   remove_entry_from_cache()
   find_in_cache()
   check_for_updates()
   ```

What is the preferred word order? Is there any?
I'm quite new to the programming but I'd like to acquire the good coding habits from the beginning. I've briefly read the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Style Guide but I didn't find the answer there.

Answer (score 3):

While this question is hard to answer objectively, I think you should go to my favorite python standard library module for this, courtesy of [Tim Peters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

```
>>> import this
```

> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested. Sparse is better than dense. Readability
>   counts. Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity. Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced. In the face of ambiguity, refuse the
>   temptation to guess. There should be one-- and preferably only one
>   --obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch. Now is better than never. Although never is often
>   better than *right* now. If the implementation is hard to explain,
>   it's a bad idea. If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a
>   good idea. Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of
>   those!

I believe `Readability counts.` is the most relevant here. With little exception, code is to be written and maintained by other humans, not machines. It should be "readable for humans" as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't really any preferred order out there and you should use the one that makes working easy and more smooth. For example, if you had a lot of variables/classes/functions with the key word "history" and "cache", with repeatable words (like "history_add" and "cache_add") using the structured version would probably be better. But in any other cases, the readable version is going to be good solution.

Answer (score 1):

For this one issue, the approach I learned has served me well as abstract data types evolved to OOP, in designs from projects of 250K lines down to student exercises.

- Objects are nouns or noun phrases
- Functions are verbs or verb phrases

When I'm programming, each line of code is a command, a verb.  I want to write it as a verb.  Thus, I prefer your option 2: `clear_history` is more easily understood than `history_clear`.

Beyond this, if you name your variables (objects) well, then your organizational wants will follow, since the object will imply the way you're using the variable.  For instance, you'll write something like

```
symbiont_browser.trim_window(x_size, y_size)
```